# Is there an std::thread_create like pthread_create?

Tags: c++, pthreads, stdthread

I'm working a project here trying to port some Linux C++ code to be cross platform, and I have here a wrapper thread class that's using `pthread`.

```
#include <pthread.h>

class ServerThread {
public:
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
   int Create (void* callback, void* args);
};
```

I'm trying to port this directly to `std::thread` but the `Create` method here uses `pthread_create` which I understand starts the thread, but I'm unable to find the `std` equivalent.

```
int ServerThread :: Create (void* callback, void* args) {
   int tret = 0;
   tret = pthread_create(&this->tid, nullptr, (void*(*)(void *)) callback, args);
   if (tret != 0) {
      std::cerr << "Error creating thread." << std::endl;
      return tret;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I genuinely don't understand what I'm looking at with that `pthread_create` function call. Is that some kind of strange void pointer double cast?

I have no documentation with the code base I'm working with, so my guess is as good as the next guys'.

Comment: I guess the closest thing to `pthread_create` would be constructing a new `std::thread` object. There isn't a direct translation.

Comment: `(void*(*)(void *))` is casting a function pointer from a `void*`. This is only conditionally supported, not all platforms allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread`'s constructor will start the new thread with the function and arguments provided.

So roughly:

```
void thread_func(int, double) {
}

class ServerThread {

    std::thread thr;

    ServerThread(int arg1, double arg2)
      : thr(thread_func, arg1, arg2) {
    }

};
```

If you want to run the thread later after the construction, you can first default-initialize `std::thread`, which will not start an actual thread, and then you can move a new `std::thread` instance with started thread into it later:

```
class ServerThread {

    std::thread thr;

    ServerThread() : thr() {
    }

    void StartThread(int arg1, double arg2) {
        thr = std::thread(thread_func, arg1, arg2);
    }

};
```